# Why does _.bindAll prevent you calling a Backbone model classProperty function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I hit an interesting bug in my code recently and although I managed to find a fix I'm wondering if someone can explain why the solution works. Here's some code

```
var Project = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    // Uncomment this line and you will no longer get the alert
    //_.bindAll(this);
  },
}, {
  parse: function() {
    alert('Parsing data');
  }
});

var project = new Project({});
project.constructor.parse();
```

I understand the bindAll, when used like this, will bind all functions to the current scope but I'm not sure why it would be affecting the `parse` class property function. I would expect it to only affect the instance properties.

Comment: What version of Underscore are you using? You might also want to note that [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) now requires that you specify the method names.

Comment: I'm still on Backbone 0.9.1 and Underscore 1.3.1 where the method names aren't required. It throws an error with a the latest Underscore version so maybe it's not worth going into any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll look at 1.4.4 as that's the last version of Underscore whose `_.bindAll` can be (successfully) called without specifying the method names.

The [`_.bindAll` implementation](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.4.4/underscore.js#L599) is quite simple and reviewing it should clear things up:

```
_.bindAll = function(obj) {
  var funcs = slice.call(arguments, 1);
  if (funcs.length === 0) funcs = _.functions(obj);
  each(funcs, function(f) { obj[f] = _.bind(obj[f], obj); });
  return obj;
};
```

The third line is the key:

```
funcs = _.functions(obj);
```

So if you don't specify the functions to bind, Underscore will grab all the object's properties that are functions and bind all of those, check the [`_.functions` implementation](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.4.4/underscore.js#L758) and [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#object-functions) for details.

But what is the `constructor` property? Well, [it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor):

> ... a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype

That will pass the `_.isFunction` test and so `constructor` will be in our `funcs` array above. That means that `constructor` will be replaced with a wrapper function in line four of `_.bindAll`:

```
obj[f] = _.bind(obj[f], obj);
```

but that wrapper function won't have any of the properties (such as `parse`) that the original `project.constructor` has and everything falls apart in a pile of confusion and nonsense.

This sort of confusion is probably why the 1.5+ [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) says:

> **bindAll** `_.bindAll(object, *methodNames)`
>
> [...] **methodNames** are required.

You can also run into other odd problems if you try to iterator through an object's properties and try to figure out which ones are functions and which ones aren't.

---

I'd encourage you to look at the Underscore and Backbone source when unexpected things happen, they're both fairly easy to read and understand.